# Импорты и сборка проекта в Golang

Tags: golang, package

Пишу небольшой проект на языке Go. Применяю такой подход в котором я инкапсулирую свой код, точнее держу в разных файлах. Но никак не могу импортнуть один в другой. Т.е.

```
package main

import (
  "log"
  "fmt"
  "github.com/.../golang_rest"
    //"github.com/gorilla/mux"
   //  _ "github.com/lib/pq"
   // _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
  "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
  _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mysql"
)


func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Index Page")
}

func main() {
  db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", "root:123456@/test?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local")

  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  } 
  defer db.Close()
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    books = append(book.books, book.Book{ID: "1", Title: "Война и Мир", Author: &Author{Firstname: "Лев", Lastname: "Толстой"}})
    books = append(book.books, book.Book{ID: "2", Title: "Преступление и наказание", Author: &Author{Firstname: "Фёдор", Lastname: "Достоевский"}})
    r.HandleFunc("/books", getBooks).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/books/{id}", getBook).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/books", createBook).Methods("POST")
    r.HandleFunc("/books/{id}", updateBook).Methods("PUT")
    r.HandleFunc("/books/{id}", deleteBook).Methods("DELETE")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r))
}
```

и вот еще один файл, который хочу импортнуть

```
package book

import (
  "github.com/gorilla/mux"
  "net/http"
  "math/rand"
  "strconv"
  "encoding/json"
)


type Book struct {
  ID      string `json:"id"`
  Title   string `json:"title"`
  Author *Author `json:"author"`
}

type Author struct {
  Firstname string `json:"firstname"`
  Lastname  string `json:"lastname"`
}


var books []Book

func getBooks(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(books)
}
```

Comment: Это не файл, а пакет. Импортируется так же как прочие пакеты.

Answer (score 0):

В go нет понятия "файл". Есть понятие "пакет". И пакет физически совпадает с именем директории. В пакете может быть множество файлов.
Пакеты внутренние импортируются ровно также как и внешние, например по относительному пути:

```go
import(
   ...
   "../users"
   ...
)
```

Отдельные нюансы по пакеты с именем "internal", но вам похоже пока об этом знать рановато.